# How come the text of my button won't change with jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to figure out why on earth my button text won't change from `download now!` to `play now!` when users are on iOS devices.  I thought this would be super simple but for some reason the button is being stubborn in terms of changing its text!

What am I doing wrong?

Here's my html:

```
<button class="appBtn imgCenter">download now!</button>
```

Here's my js:

```
var user_agent = this.userAgent();

if (user_agent == "ios") {
   $('.appBtn').html('Play Now');
}

this.userAgent = function(){
if (navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/i) || navigator.userAgent.match(/iPad/i) {
  return "ios";
}
```

Comment: How are you setting `user_agent`?

Comment: `$('.appBtn').html('Play Now');` is working as expected

Comment: The problem is almost certainly with the code that assigns `user_agent`, not the code you posted above.

Comment: @Barmar I posted it

Comment: Please post the code that sets the `user_agent` variable.

Comment: @Barmar Posted it now

Comment: Use `console.log(user_agent)` to verify that it's working correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Better to use `navigator.platform`, this would solve your problem

```js
if ( /iPad|iPhone|iPod/.test(navigator.platform) ) {
   $('.appBtn').html('Play Now');
}
```

```html
<button class="appBtn imgCenter">download now!</button>
```